# Getting the same answer every time

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a website with bootstrap, on the website i have 3 x 3 div rows.
I want that in every row some information will be shown from my database, i get it worked but now i have the following problem.

I use the same code for every div so he shows the same answer in every row and i want that there will be different information in every row and not the same over and over.

I want to show a schedule of events in my country and they need to be ordered by time ASC.

so my questions is how can i get it worked? that in every row the visitor sees different events and not the same event in every row.

this is my code:

```
<div class="box col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
<?php

    include 'connection.php'; 

    $sql = "SELECT id, artiest, start_time, end_time, locatie,  plaats FROM evenementen  GROUP BY id ORDER BY start_time, end_time ASC limit 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo 
            "<ul> 
               <li>" . $row["artiest"]. "</li>
               <li>" . Substr($row["start_time"], 0, 5) . " - " . Substr($row["end_time"], 0, 5) . "</li>
               <li>" . $row["locatie"] . "</li>
               <li>" . $row["plaats"] . "</li>
            </ul>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use foreach (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to loop the query and display a row for each event.

Comment: @Yavor; he's using a `while` loop, which is the correct manner of looping through a database query's results. @user3405085 From the code shown, the while loop is commented out. `// output data of each row while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())` - but I think that might be from how you've pasted the code. Can you edit to show your code properly.

Comment: What does this have to do with CSS?..or Bootstrap for that matter?

Comment: does other eight divs have the same code as above? then you should set limit like `LIMIT 1,1`, `LIMIT 2,1` etc. in each of them starting from higher row count.

Comment: Peter below is correct. The reason is that mysql returns only one result because of LIMIT 1.

Comment: Peter is correct, get rid of the LIMIT 1 and move your loop outside the DIV

Comment: all the 12 div's have the same code as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `limit 1` at the end of your query does exactly that, it limits the amount of results to 1. Als your div should be inside the loop, instead of manually creating 12 divs. Try this:

```
<?php

include 'connection.php'; 

$sql = "SELECT id, artiest, start_time, end_time, locatie,  plaats FROM evenementen  GROUP BY id ORDER BY start_time, end_time ASC limit 9";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo 
        "<div class='box col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12'>
            <ul> 
             <li>" . $row["artiest"]. "</li>
             <li>" . Substr($row["start_time"], 0, 5) . " - " . Substr($row["end_time"], 0, 5) . "</li>
             <li>" . $row["locatie"] . "</li>
             <li>" . $row["plaats"] . "</li>
          </ul>
        </div>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: yeah i know but if i remove it, i get multiple results in one div and not 1 result each div

Comment: @Peter is correct, get rid of the LIMIT 1 and move your loop outside the DIV.

Comment: no it's not if there are more than 9 entries in db. there should be at least limit for this 9 records (3x3 is not equal to 12)

Comment: still wrong. Limit 0,8 will fetch first 8 records not 9.

Comment: Apparently together we will get there in the end.. @Glapa

Answer (score 0):

Remove `limit 1` from query and put `div` inside `while` loop

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<div class="box col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">';//Add this here
            echo
            "<ul> 
                             <li>" . $row["artiest"] . "</li>
                             <li> " . Substr($row["start_time"], 0, 5) . " - " . Substr($row["end_time"], 0, 5) . "</li>
                             <li> " . $row["locatie"] . "</li>
                             <li> " . $row["plaats"] . "</li>
                             </ul>";
         echo '</div>';//and close here
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
```